# How to set image with text in modular large complication?

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-3, apple-watch-complication

I want to design modular large complication for watch app. In my complication view, I want to the user both image & text.

I have some of the design related question, which is as below:

1. How can I set image & text both in multiple rows of complication view?
2. Maximum how many lines modular large complication can support for display purpose?
3. How can I create multiple complications for the same family like for Circular small complication type having Ring, Simple & Stack for a single application?

I already check module large complication apple document, but I am not getting enough information. [Apple Doc:- Modular large complication](https://developer.apple.com/reference/clockkit/clkcomplicationtemplatemodularlargetable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How can I set image & text both in multiple rows of complication view?**

You are looking to the wrong type of complications actually, you need to check the [CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeColumns](https://developer.apple.com/reference/clockkit/clkcomplicationtemplatemodularlargecolumns).

You can use the below code to get idea how to create it:

```
func createTemplateForModularLarge() -> CLKComplicationTemplate {
        let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeColumns()
        template.row1ImageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: ""))
        template.row2ImageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: ""))
        template.row3ImageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: ""))
        template.row1Column1TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "")
        template.row2Column1TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "")
        template.row3Column1TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "")
        return template
    }
```

**Maximum how many lines modular large complication can support for display purpose?**

You can max use 3 rows for the CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeColumns type.

**How can I create multiple complications for the same family like for Circular small complication type having Ring, Simple & Stack for a single application?**

Seems you can't create more then one type for the same family for single applications.